# How to delete core data entries through table view by getting the index value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am using this code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == favouritesTable) {
    cellValue = [licensePlateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else { // handle search results table view
    cellValue = [filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {
            cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
        }

    }

}
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
pressRecongnizer.view.tag = indexPath.row;
//code added
[pressRecongnizer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:@"index"];
toDeleteObject = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
[pressRecongnizer release];

   // NSIndexPath *indexPathValue = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
   // [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

  //  NSLog(@"indexPathValue: %@", indexPathValue);

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

Favouritesdata *favdata = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[cell ignition] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignition_flag.png"]];
[[cell direction] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"south.png"]];

cell.licPlate.text = [favdata licenseplate];

NSLog(@"cellvalue for cellforRow: %@", cell.licPlate.text);

return cell;
}
```

and in UILongPressGestureRecognizer code:

```
- (void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}

int index = [[recognizer valueForKey:@"index"] intValue];

NSLog(@"indexNew: %i", index);

VehicleListCell* cell = (VehicleListCell *)[recognizer view];

cellValueForLongPress = cell.licPlate.text;

NSLog(@"cell value: %@", cellValueForLongPress);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;

NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [favouritesTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

[favouritesTable selectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection 
                       animated:NO 
                 scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

NSLog(@"NSIndexPath *tableSelection = %@", tableSelection );

alert.tag = recognizer.view.tag;

NSLog(@"alert.tag: %d", alert.tag);

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Remove from Favourites"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Show on Map"];

[alert show];
}
```

In this code I have applied gesture recognizer, it has a dialog box which gives option to the user to delete the core data entry. Here the issue I am getting is that, I am unable to get the exact data entry value which is to be deleted, like it doesn't matter whichever cell/row is clicked the only core data entry will be deleted residing at index-0.
I have spent many days to resolve this issue but not getting through.

Please guide me in this issue...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing an important point about cellForRowAtIndexPath, in that it re-uses existing cell objects for scrolling performance. So above where you call [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecognizer] you end up with multiple recognizers attached. You should only add it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check method names once, i did not checked them

```
-(void)tableCellPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gust{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (id)gust.view;
    NSIndexPath *ip = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```